# sending mail with link and parameter in PHP

Tags: php, parameters, gmail, sendmail

I have a strange issue with sending a mail with php, here is my code:

```
$link = "http://www.somelink/verify.php?id=".$uniqID;

$message ="<html><head></head><body><p>Full Name:".$data[0]." ".$data[1]."</p>";
$message .="<p>Flight Number: ".$data[4]."</p>";
$message .="<p>The Ride: ".$curPlace." to ".$data[5]."</p>";
$message .="<p>Number of Passengers: ".$data[3]."</p>";
$message .="<p>Date:".$data[6]." time:".$data[7]."</p>";
$message .="<p>The price: ".$data[8]."</p>";
$message .="<p>To verify the reservation press this <a href=".$link.">link</a></p></body></html>";

$headers = 'From: my@email.com' . "\r\n" .'Reply-To: some@email.com';
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Sensitivity: Personal"."\r\n";
$sent=mail($data[2],"Taxi Reservation",$message, $headers);
if($sent){
    echo "Message was sent to ".$data[2];
}
else{
    echo "Message was not sent";
}
```

The problem is with Gmail.If I send it as is, I get the success message, but get nothing in my gmail, but do get in another not gmail account.
BUT!
If I delete a tag from this line:
`$message .="<p>To verify the reservation press this <a href=".$link.">link</a></p></body></html>";`
I do get the message in Gmail.So I can't understand what's the problem.
What can couse this problem?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your link `href` isn't quoted, for one. Try `"<a href=\"$link\">link</a>"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your email is not arriving at Gmail, but the same code sending the same email is arriving at a different account, I suspect that the problem is that Gmail are seeing your email and classifying it as spam - have you checked to see if it's gone into your spam folder instead of your inbox?

Gmail has a set of rules to identify what they think is spam - presumably, including the link is enough to push your email into the spam category.

Comment: Yes you are right.Gmail sends it to spam folder, but i don'tunderstand why it sends it to spam.

Comment: They will have a list of criteria for emails that they use to classify them as spam. You're adding an explicit `From` and `Reply-to` header in the email, which is a trick that a lot of spammers use, and I assume that combined with the link, it's setting off enough warnings to be classed as a spam. There's no easy way to distinguish between 'I'm adding headers because I'm sending mail from a webserver and the default headers are meaningless' and 'I'm adding headers because I'm a spammer'. That said - do you need an explicit Reply-to header? Could you just use the From instead?

Comment: I don't really need the Reply-to.I have tried this, and it works now!
Thank you!!!